# Listbox databinding NewItemPlaceholder

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have an observable collection bound to a list box.
The collection has 2 items, but the list box is showing 3 items (e.g. the 2 items that are actually in the observable collection and an additional item for the NewItemPlaceholder.

I want it only to show the 2 items.

Below is my XAML.

```
<ListBox MinHeight="20" MinWidth="20" Name="MultipleSelectionsMultipleWagersListBox"  Visibility="{Binding Path=Coupon.BarcodeText, Converter={StaticResource CouponBarcodeToVisibilityConverter1}, ConverterParameter=994450_994550}" Height="AUto" Width="Auto" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="5"
         ItemsSource="{Binding Path=BetViewModels}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" >
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <View:BetView  DataContext="{Binding}" Name="ThisBet" Margin="5"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Here is the c#

```
  private ObservableCollection<BetViewModel> _betViewModels = new ObservableCollection<BetViewModel>();
    public ObservableCollection<BetViewModel> BetViewModels
    {
        get { return _betViewModels; }
        set
        {
            if (Equals(value, _betViewModels)) return;
            _betViewModels = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("BetViewModels");
        }
    }
```

Here is the code to populate the betViewModels:

```
var betViewModel = new BetViewModel { Bet = new Bet() };
betViewModel.Bet.SelectionName = "Chelsea";
betViewModel.Bet.Price = "4/9";
betViewModel.Bet.Market = "90 Minutes";
betViewModel.Bet.ExpectedOdd = DateTime.Now;
BetViewModels.Add(betViewModel);

betViewModel = new BetViewModel { Bet = new Bet() };
betViewModel.Bet.SelectionName = "Chelsea";
betViewModel.Bet.Price = "4/9";
betViewModel.Bet.Market = "90 Minutes";
betViewModel.Bet.ExpectedOdd = DateTime.Now;
BetViewModels.Add(betViewModel);
```

How Do I switch of this from showing the additional item for the new item place

Here is an image of it displaying the placeholder

[image]

Comment: Nothing in what you've shown here indicates anything about the problem that you're having. This isn't something that happens with a ListBox by itself so something else you're doing with the ItemsSource is causing this.

Comment: @ John Bowen, is it because we are using a DataTemplate (which is shown above)?

Comment: No. As I said, it's not related to anything you've shown here. You need to show what you're doing with your ItemsSource collection.

Comment: Hi John, I've added the  ItemsSource and the c# code it is bound to now.

Comment: You have to show the code which populates the itemsource too, not only the property!

Comment: @sine that code is now added (that populates the betviewmodels).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The DataGrid supports adding new rows, which have to start out blank. If your ItemsSource is bound to both a ListBox/ItemsControl and a DataGrid, you need to set the DataGrid 'CanUserAddRows' property to 'False'.

Where I found the answer: http://www.mindstick.com/Forum/1519/How%20do%20I%20remove%20a%20listbox%20new%20item%20placeholder

Answer (score 3):

There's nothing in your code that should be adding an extra empty item. There may be some other code adding to BetViewModels or there may be a change happening to the generated ICollectionView for the collection if you have it bound to something else that you're not showing, like an editable DataGrid.

Answer (score 0):

did your sample code also provide this issue?

how much items contains your _betViewModels.count in debugging there are really only 2 Items?

it seems you added an empty `BetViewModel` at the End

i would suggest check your logic which provides populates your items

- if it is a loop it should `(counter<yourDatasource.Count)` just for example